# jQuery select <br> tags and wrap spaces around it

Tags: jquery, replace

For example I have this markup:

```
Test text<br>
test2 text
```

That 
 inside it needs to have a space before, and after. Like this

```
" <br> "
```

So I can split the whole text and get a complete list like this:

```
Test
text
<br>
test2
text
```

I do the splitting with this code:

```
var words = text.split(" ");
    //            console.log("words:" + words);
for ( var i = 0, l = words.length; i<l; ++i ) {
    //  console.log(i +": "+words[i] );
}
```

I have some code to answer my question.  Not complete yet, I need your help.

```
// Replace all "<br>" to " <br> "             
$("#artikel br").each(function(){
   alert($(this).index()));
});
```

Comment: Can you specify what exactly is "not working"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#artikel").html(function(index, oldhtml){
    return oldhtml.replace(/\<br\>/gi, "&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;"); 
});
```

`html` [docs](http://docs)

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hgt7X/1/)

Comment: you should use `&nbsp;` instead of spaces